# Why is an asham of greater holiness than a pesach offering?

Tags: korban, korbanos-ketores-prayers, korban-pesach

The korbanot section in the daily siddur (Zevachim 5) describes the types of korbanot, where they were offered and the level of holiness of each type.  Why are ashamot (guilt offerings) of greater holiness than pesach offerings (kodshi kodoshim vs kodshim kalim)?  The Pesach is required of all people, annually.  An asham is only brought by individuals who have sinned.  Why is my naive conception of holiness (brought by everyone annually being more holy than individuals seeking to atone for sins) wrong?

This question asks about the meaning of the term holy, in one practical application.

Comment: VTC as Unclear. Seems many people are really unsure what you want.

Comment: Do you want to know in general philosophically why some korbanot are ranked higher than others? How it is derived that they are higher? What implications their higher holiness has? Is there something unique about these particular example offerings that you choose them as the only rankings that don't make sense? Are you curious about the origin of the nomenclature of different rankings? Doesn't seem like people understand what you want. "Why" is such a broad request.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's permitted to eat. only for males Cohanim and needs to be slaughtered only at the north of the Mizbeach as the 5th chapter of Zvachim included in the Dayly Siddur states. The holiness is measured by the amount of restriction. Holly is Kodesh. For Nedarim that prohibits objects, for marriage that prohibits a woman to other men, we use words of Kodesh to indicate the prohibition.

Comment: Why does slaughter in the north of the Mizbeach make a sacrifice more holy? Yes, this is written in the Mishna, but what is the logic that makes the north (or the sacrifices there) more holy? The north is not closer to the Kodesh Kadashim.

Comment: A greater restriction where to slaughter

Comment: Logically one could make the case that the legal ability to sacrifice anywhere would indicate a higher level of holiness.  Why is a restriction to the north an indication of greater holiness rather than less holiness?  (As an analogy, a master key can open many doors, so is called "master" not "minor".)

Comment: So a chulin animal is better than a Korban ?